# SQL Server: Arithmetic function on BIGINT loses precision

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2000. If a new version will solve this problem, I'll upgrade.

Consider the following records in a `bigint` column:

```
1000000000000000000
1000000200000000000
1000000200000100000
1000000200000000001
1000000200000000100
```

I thought the following `SELECT` statement would yield 1 record, but it comes back with an empty set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE number/100 <> FLOOR(number/100)
```

If SQL Server provides a `BIGINT` data type, surely it should handle the arithmetic also?

Comment: If upgrading is on the table why not just upgrade? 2000 has been out of support for pushing a decade now. Given your example I don't see where anything is not working as it should be.

Comment: Agree with @Sean Lange. You should be at least on 2008R2 if this is a serious application.

Answer (score 4):

An INT divided by an INT returns an INT.  Just add a decimal to your denom

```
Declare @Table table (number bigint)
Insert into @Table values
(1000000000000000000),
(1000000200000000000),
(1000000200000100000),
(1000000200000000001),
(1000000200000000100)

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE number/100. <> FLOOR(number/100.)
```

Returns

```
mumber
1000000200000000001
```

Comment: Well that's funky. I tried this on 2005, 2008R2, 2012 and 2014. All three versions exhibit this behavior and the calculation is the same.

Comment: @SeanLange with or without the decimal on the denom?

Comment: SELECT * 
 , number/100.
 , FLOOR(number/100.)
 , (number/100.) / FLOOR(number/100.)
FROM @Table WHERE number/100. <> FLOOR(number/100.)

Comment: Thanks John, it worked.  I did also reason in your way at first, but I noticed when I tried a bigger denom e.g. 10000 or 1000000 (as bigints no decimal), it gave the result i was after, so I didn't continue that train of thought.